# Delocalization of eigenvectors in Expanding Graphs

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given an adjacency matrix A, can we say something about whether the eigenvectors corresponding to its highest(or second-highest) eigenvalues are delocalized ? By delocalization I mean that every coordinate in the vector has nearly the same absolute value. Are there existing results regarding this for expanders ?